# How to unit test the ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

Can any one give me the example to unit test the ASP.NET MVC view? IS it possible to unit test the view page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in views' unit-testing because it is an representation object, there should be no logic which should be unit tested.

To test representations it's better to choose another testing technics like functional testing. There are different tools for that, for example Selenium and Cucumber.

Comment: but sometimes viewmodel can be valid but will fail when loaded by view, so maybe test only if rendering is ok should be enough.